# c# で StreamReaderクラスのReadLine(). を使ったTCP/IP通信の強制終了のさせ方

Tags: c#

C#でStreamReaderクラスのReadLine()を使ってTCP/IP通信を行っています。

```
public NetworkStream netStream;
public StreamWriter serverWriter = null;
public StreamReader serverReader = null;

netStream = server.GetStream();
serverReader = new StreamReader(netStream, Encoding.UTF8);
serverWriter = new StreamWriter(netStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis"));

// スレッド内の処理
lock (this) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            string message = reader.ReadLine();

            if (message != null) {
                // 受信データの内容を解析
                PerseData(message);
            }
            else {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (IsKill) {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

このReadLine()はTimeout値を設定していませんので、データが来るか、それともクライアントからのDisconnectが来るまで終了しません。
これだと、クライアントが異常終了してしまう、または通信ができない状態になると、ReadLine()から永久に抜けられなくなります。

そこで、クライアントからではなく、自身でReadLine()を抜ける正攻法というのをご存知の方おられますでしょうか？以前Timeout値を設定して行っていたのですが、Timeout値だと一度だけしかきかないので別の方法を探しております。

Comment: タイトルにある「TCP/IP通信の強制終了」であればソケットが破棄されることは自明ですが、本文にある「ReadLine()を抜ける正攻法」ではソケットを維持するとも受け取れます。どちらの意図での質問でしょうか、明確にしてください。

Comment: すいません、書き方が悪かったです。
目的はTCP/IP通信を終わらせたいのですが、ReadLine() から永久に抜けないので終わらせる事が出来ないのが現状なのです。
よって、何らかの方法でReadLine()から抜けることさえできればそれで目的は達しますので、タイトルはその過程を端折ってしまっております。ですので意図的には「ReadLine(‌​)を抜ける正攻法」でお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

タイムアウトを設定するのが正攻法です。

TCPソケット自体はタイムアウトが発生しても接続を再使用できる仕様となっておりますので、タイムアウトが発生した場合は`StreamReader.DiscardBufferData()`を呼んでから再通信を行えば規格レベルでは問題はないはずです。再通信が正常に動作すれば処理を続行すればよいですし、問題があるようなら再試行の時間を空けたり、`NetworkStream`自体を再度作成しなおすようにします。

一方スレッドやタスクなどを使用して例えば

```
Task.WhenAny(streamReader.ReadLineAsync(), Task.Delay(timeout));
```

のように他スレッドで時間を区切ることも可能ですが、`StreamReader`からアクセスされている`NetworkStream`をキャンセルするには接続自体を破棄するしかありません。ですので実現できる挙動はタイムアウト1回ごとに再接続を行うのと大差がなく、わざわざ実装する必要性はないです。

Answer (score 0):

ストリームではなく非同期サーバーソケットを使えばクライアントから切断されたことも
わかりますよ。
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx